# arbitrary type definition gives: Property 'x' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

it seems [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300033/typescript-indexed-properties-constraint-checks-working-on-raw-types-but-not-on) is related, yet I dont understand.

here is an example of what I want:

`myObj` should accept the following settings:

```
myObj = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'};
myObj = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': {'key2': 'val2', 'btnWrap': true}, 'key3': 'val3'};
```

So I came up with the following type definition:

```
let myObj: {[key: string]: string | {[key: string]: string, btnWrap: boolean}}
```

> Property 'btnWrap' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.ts(2411)

(I dont understand the above error message.)

Please note:

- key1, 2, 3 stand for ARBITRARY key-names.
- in `'key2': {'key2': 'val2', 'btnWrap': true}` please note it should be the SAME arbitrary key-name. (key2 for eg)

Im happy for some guidance.

---

@Evert:

```
let myObj: {
  [key: string]: string | boolean,
  btnWrap: boolean
}

myObj = {'arr0': 'val0', 'arr1': {'arr1': 'val1', 'btnWrap': false}};
```

> Type '{ 'arr1': string; 'btnWrap': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'.
>     Type '{ 'arr1': string; 'btnWrap': boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2322)

Comment: You are saying that key1, 2 3 stand for ARBITRARY key-names, but then you want the inner object declaration to include this arbitrary key? Can you give a real example?

Comment: I have two examples gilamran. See also my edit. Is anything still unclear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is because the `btnWrap` type `boolean` doesn't match the [string index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) type `string`.  The type `{[key: string]: string, btnWrap: boolean}}` is trying to say that every property has a string value *and* that `btnWrap` has a boolean value.  They can't both be true, so the compiler warns you.

---

There isn't a single concrete type `MyObj` that represents the constraint as you described it.  But you *can* create a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type which takes the union of key literals `K` and produces a type `MyObj<K>`:

```
type MyObj<K extends keyof any> = 
  { [P in K]: string | (Record<P, string> & { btnWrap: boolean }) };
```

The type `MyObj<K>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where each property with key `P` either has value type `string`, or the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of `{btnWrap: boolean}` with `Record<P, string>`.  The latter type is itself a mapped type ([defined in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1449-L1454)) with keys `P` and properties `string`.  So each property of `MyObject<K>` must either look like `someKey: string` or `someKey: {btnWrap: boolean, someKey: string}`.

Again, to describe the type of `myObj`, instead of something simple like `let myObj: MyObj = ...`, you have to do something like `let myObj: MyObj<"key1"|"key2"|"key3"> = ...` where you specify the generic parameters.  To prevent you from having to do this yourself, you can use a generic helper function to help [*infer*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) the type of `K` given an object, like this:

```
const asMyObj = <T extends MyObj<keyof T>>(myObj: T) => myObj;
```

Now let's try it:

```
let myObj1 = asMyObj({ key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3' });
let myObj2 = asMyObj({ key1: 'val1', key2: { key2: 'val2', btnWrap: true }, key3: 'val3' });
```

Those work just fine.  Now let's see what goes wrong if you violate your constraint:

```
let badMyObj1 = asMyObj({ key1: 1 }); 
// error, number is bad

let badMyObj2 = asMyObj({ key1: "val1", key2: { key2: "val2" } }); 
// error, missing btnWrap

let badMyObj3 = asMyObj({ key1: "val1", key2: { btnWrap: true } }); 
// error, missing key2 inside value

let badMyObj4 = asMyObj({ key1: "val1", key2: { key3: "val3", btnWrap: true } }); 
// error, key3 not expected inside value
```

Those errors are probably what you want to see, right?

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Here's a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#src=type%20MyObj%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20any%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20%28Record%3CP%2C%20string%3E%20%26%20%7B%20btnWrap%3A%20boolean%20%7D%29%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20asMyObj%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20MyObj%3Ckeyof%20T%3E%3E%28myObj%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20myObj%3B%0A%0Alet%20myObj1%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%20%27val1%27%2C%20key2%3A%20%27val2%27%2C%20key3%3A%20%27val3%27%20%7D%29%3B%0Alet%20myObj2%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%20%27val1%27%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%20key2%3A%20%27val2%27%2C%20btnWrap%3A%20true%20%7D%2C%20key3%3A%20%27val3%27%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0Alet%20badMyObj1%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%201%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20number%20is%20bad%0Alet%20badMyObj2%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%20%22val1%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%20key2%3A%20%22val2%22%20%7D%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20missing%20btnWrap%0Alet%20badMyObj3%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%20%22val1%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%20btnWrap%3A%20true%20%7D%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20missing%20key2%20inside%20value%0Alet%20badMyObj4%20%3D%20asMyObj%28%7B%20key1%3A%20%22val1%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%20key3%3A%20%22val3%22%2C%20btnWrap%3A%20true%20%7D%20%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20key3%20not%20expected%20inside%20value%0A) to the above code.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you, you seem to have a PHD in typing :D. Well thats well above me. I think I'll use @gilamran approach because the checking is not thaaaat crucial, but your answer is definitaly some gold!!

Comment: I was just about to edit my answer and use `Record`... Cool answer @jcalz!

Answer (score 1):

You type is defined like this:

- All the properties should be a string or some inner type (`InnerObj`)
- The InnerObj properties should be a string or a boolean

This is how to define it:

```
type InnerObj = {
  [key: string]: string | boolean;
  btnWrap: boolean;
};

type Obj = {
  [key: string]: string | InnerObj;
}

const myObj1: Obj = { key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3' };
const myObj2: Obj = { key1: 'val1', key2: { key2: 'val2', btnWrap: true }, key3: 'val3' };
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution is the best i got so far, but: `const myObj1: Obj = {'arr0': 'true', 'arr1': {'otherKeyNameThanArr1': 'val1', 'btnWrap': false}};` should not work.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible, I'm investigating it