# Is there a way to build a type interface with dynamic field name?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I want to build a type around the lines of :

```
interface Type<ofWhat>'fieldName'{
    fieldName: ofWhat[];
    otherProps: any;
}
```

Because the API endpoint has this weird design.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
type Page<T> = {pageInfo: PageInfo} | {[key:string]: Array<T>}
```

In which can subscribe to objects like :

```
    const obj2:Page<Card> = {
  pageInfo: {
    totalItens: 0,
    totalPages: 0,
    pageNumber: 0,
    lastPage: true
  },
  cards: [
    {
      header: "string",
      title: "string",
      content: "string",
      lawsuitId: "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
    },
  ]
}
```

However, this is problematic for the linter that doesn't understand that `cards` is a dynamic name and mark as an error.

Any ideas to improve this interface design?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774361/typescript-interface-key-string

Comment: This was what I've done. But have the problems of linter and static type checking. But thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Record<>` with a constrained type for the key [seems to check out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgBTgc2gXigbzOiASQDsAzAewC4pUMSKBfAbgChRIaCAeAaQhCgQAHsAjEAJgigJgAJwCWxNABooAFXAQAfFGzwktaADIoAJQgBjcrPG9+qjZADaAXS2sWwsNeBRFo2VI4C2gAYTgbXBYoGKgACwg4cQhZaliZBSVWWKhgeWAAGwg09LlFNGzYq2JRGpKM8sqYgrgAdwQAV3zCcWoGrJYGFk8hb1lffxSgkM46MnIonOByYDgCwlqEamIOgFsAIxSm3JW1wy2oHYOj6Nj8DAA5PcPUy+ebnJaZQxL98nIinBiKwhmxNFBwjZDLpZhAuAByCwRSTw1SQ8TuYbVGRQcj7ABWACZqOjodgcLd7kR5tQKUtTutNtQAAzKW4xZarArnFlsnJUp7XV6s9lQL7AH65WQdCC3Bh8qBImwXJyiuk5eKJZKvABE-TQOoVS3yRWoerKSkNopi1VqwDN+qtGrFbU63V6UB1AGYggAOACspAAbAAWAC0-oA7ABGSNhkP+oOEsP7H0WMOEiwATiDPqDQbgQSDOtF8tuLjZzCAA)...

```
type BasePage = { pageInfo: PageInfo };
type Page<Key extends string, Type> = BasePage & Record<Key, Type[]>;

interface Card {
  header: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  lawsuitId: string;
}

interface PageInfo {
  totalItens: number;
  totalPages: number;
  pageNumber: number;
  lastPage: boolean;
}

type CardPage = Page<"cards", Card>;

const obj2: CardPage = {
  pageInfo: {
    totalItens: 0,
    totalPages: 0,
    pageNumber: 0,
    lastPage: true,
  },
  cards: [
    {
      header: "string",
      title: "string",
      content: "string",
      lawsuitId: "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    },
  ],
};
```