# How to have a type with both [key: string] and id in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out a way to get rid of this error "Property 'pending' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to 'string' index type"

I've found this stackoverflow: [arbitrary type definition gives: Property 'x' of type 'boolean' is not assignable to string index type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244493/arbitrary-type-definition-gives-property-x-of-type-boolean-is-not-assignabl)
it's not the exact same but I tried to take the logic and do something similar but no success.

Here is what I've tried so far

```
type MyObj<K extends keyof any> ={ [P in K]: Record<P, string> & { btnWrap: boolean } };
const asMyObj = <T extends MyObj<keyof T>>(myObj: T) => myObj;

let myObj31 = asMyObj({ key1: 'val1', pending: true});


// -------------


type InnerObj = {
  [key: string]: string | boolean;
  pending: boolean;
};


const myObj32: InnerObj = { pending: true, key1: { id: 'val1' }, key2: { id:'val2'} };

// -------------

type customType = {
  [key: string]: { id: string };
  pending: boolean;
};

const myObj33: customType = { pending: true, key1: { id: 'val1' }, key2: { id:'val2'} };

// Some of these taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244493/arbitrary-type-definition-gives-property-x-of-type-boolean-is-not-assignabl
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVgHgNJQgD2BAdgCYDOUA1hCAPYBmUAhviAHxQC8A3lANoAKUAS3xR0AXQBcUAEoQAxlQBOhVLwA0UYsAVCA5qwBkULomD4A6gvphJiKlQA2ERlAC+rgNwAoefk0NicEjI7FCoACpYuAQksAgoqBTUdGHMzAAUALZxyJJhAJTsrFlBXp6OwFDFKADMAIwh9AHZaVyJtZIA5ABu9Pa1HeqQRLqSWgCuEC55pZ4A9LNQALTLK6srnhugkFAAkvj4EApBIRyeUDyJkpra+DoSGlq6UAA+ULYOTvhe50OEI292RyMLwuGY+PxVZDVABMkj2ByOKBOUF+-3GEHUbUkXAEhE6PT6HVcmMosKMgjx3V60I6blBG3mSzWzMWm3A0FkY00VAyYXZJzOF0oV0et3uOLxDxuOg8gtRtxsgM+INK4IqkOq1UknO5vP5bHJ8p0owUExJIHa5Nx+N6-WJ5FJ2Ip4ip9hpdNKjIAyjzoLQoMAABYQYjQYD0CjCGgKHlQQPAYBgYjieaaeiyMhULqHGj2KgAdwAdPIMrMAI4TTQCKi+WYAVjr0IALC2AJzVWb0BSIARaLsgRZbCCLQgQGhCXvV-CLHQCbPERZgGOQBSgRbYRa0QfsxbvIHTgQL-BUYCLRrEAQ6fD0RD2IA)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's nothing great in TypeScript for the "rest index signature" use case, unfortunately.  See the linked question and answers for more information.  Taking your playground and the example at the top I could write [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8rjw), but such things all have drawbacks without native TS support.